# Restrict survival time to first five years since diagnosis

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival

I need to restrict the follow-up time in my survival analysis to five years after diagnosis.
However, I'm not sure which function to use.

I'm using the `Surv` function for the analysis:

`coxph(Surv(Time, Event)  ~ education, data = data_Cox)`

I need to restrict the variable "Time" to a maximum of five years, and after that, the persons need to be censored.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ifelse()` function twice, once to change the Event indicator and once to change the Time variable. You can read the documentation by running `?ifelse` or searching online

```r
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(Time = rexp(10, rate = 0.2),
                  Event = rbinom(10, 1, 0.8))
print(dat)
#>          Time Event
#> 1   4.2172863     1
#> 2   2.8830514     0
#> 3   6.6452743     0
#> 4   0.1578868     1
#> 5   0.2810549     1
#> 6   1.5825061     0
#> 7   1.5711365     1
#> 8   0.7263340     1
#> 9  13.6311823     1
#> 10  0.1457672     1
dat$NewTime <- ifelse(dat$Time >= 5,
                      5, dat$Time)
dat$NewEvent <- ifelse(dat$Time >= 5,
                       0, dat$Event)
print(dat)
#>          Time Event   NewTime NewEvent
#> 1   4.2172863     1 4.2172863        1
#> 2   2.8830514     0 2.8830514        0
#> 3   6.6452743     0 5.0000000        0
#> 4   0.1578868     1 0.1578868        1
#> 5   0.2810549     1 0.2810549        1
#> 6   1.5825061     0 1.5825061        0
#> 7   1.5711365     1 1.5711365        1
#> 8   0.7263340     1 0.7263340        1
#> 9  13.6311823     1 5.0000000        0
#> 10  0.1457672     1 0.1457672        1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Bad practice to do destructive editing of a column like Time. Instead should create a new column.

Comment: Fair point, edited

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea offered by @DavidLukeThiessen is sound but .. Bad practice to do destructive editing of columns like 'Time' and 'Event' and using `ifelse` is rather inefficient.

Instead should create a new column. Also could do this

```
 dat$Event2 <- NA
 dat$Time2 <- NA
 dat$Event2[dat$Time >5] <- 0 
 dat$Time2[ dat$Time > 5 ] <- 5`
```

Comment: You need to initialize Event2 and Time2 with the existing values. Otherwise this is indeed faster than ifelse.